# How do i remove the black borders from the background?

Tags: color, boxes, mdframed

I want to remove the black border around the colored box. How can i do that?
And also change the lenght and with of the box

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts, fancyhdr, color, comment, graphicx, environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20]
text here.
\end{mdframed}
```

Comment: please always check the code you post produces the problem you describe, the code here can not be run, missing `\begin{document}` at least, and it includes packages not needed for the example, it just makes it harder for people to test answers.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the page background is white, all you need to do is add the option

```
 linecolor=white
```

to the list of options passed to the `mdframed` environment:

```
 \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20,linecolor=white]
```

Comment: i used '\newenvironment{Background}[0]
    { \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=purple!20,
    topline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rectangle]  }
    {  \end{mdframed}}' You know how i can change the size?

Comment: @AndersJensen - Please clarify what you mean by "size": the height, the width, something else?

Comment: Yeah i want to customize the height and the width

Comment: @AndersJensen - Your follow-up question is rather broad, and the likelihood that I'll guess correctly what about width and height you want to change is thus negligible. All I can do is suggest that you study section 6.3 of the package's user guide.

Answer (score 2):

`mdframed` has the option `hidealllines` to hide all lines.

This feature is well documented in the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20, hidealllines=true]
text here.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! i used `topline=false, rightline=false, leftline=false, bottomline=false` you know i change the size?

Comment: @AndersJensen: Do yourself a favor and try to get accustomed to use the manual of `mdframed`. If you are used to your pdf-viewer you should get the answer to your own question within seconds.

Comment: i did but a quick CTRL + F found me nothing when i searched for widht, height, size .

Comment: Try to search for `margin`